# Unable to send/receive from microcontroller virtual serial port

Tags: windows-8.1, serial-port, microcontroller

I have a MSP430 Launchpad (microcontroller) which forms a virtual serial port on my Windows 8.1 rig. Somehow I cannot receive/send any data through this serial port on this rig. I have tried 2 other PCs (both Windows 7) and they work fine, so I suppose we can rule out the possibility of a faulty microcontroller. The device appears to be fine in device manager (no exclamation or error marks) but does not appear when I run PortMon, any idea how can I run further diagnostics to narrow down the offending driver(s)?

Comment: Does the device appears under **Ports (COM & LPT)** node?

Comment: Yes it does, but no data comes in/out

Comment: Maybe it obvious but have you tried changing the COM number? Have you checked the bps and parity configuration?

Comment: Yup, I have tried that to no avail

Comment: TI driver includes FTDI driver in the ZIP file. Have you installed them? http://www.ti.com/tool/msp-exp430g2#technicaldocuments

Comment: Which one? If it's 430cdc.inf I have tried that before

Comment: In this ZIP file: http://www.ti.com/lit/zip/slac632 there is two directories. Both seem to be different drivers for USB-Serial. Even those inside stellaris directory. Which are the FTDI I mentioned before.

Comment: The stellaris drivers are for a ARM processor, I tried with the ones under slac632\msp430\USB_CDC and they are the same